# How can I make crispy chips?

Tags: chips

I made potato chips by following [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/potato-chips/), but they didn't come out crispy. 
What is the accurate temperature for frying chips?

Note (from Jefromi): my best guess based on the comments is that the OP didn't use this recipe, but rather fried thin potato slices in a deep-fryer at 180C, in an unknown oil, for an  unknown amount of time. If this is enough to let you answer, just go for it.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a bit more information than that. I assume "the common way" means deep frying? What temperature did you fry them at? For how long? How were the potatoes sliced? What kind of potatoes were they? And... just to make sure, you are talking about [potato chips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_chip), right? Not [french fries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_fries)?

Comment: ya.potato chips

Comment: Potato chips are normally fried, not microwaved. Why are you asking about temperature if you're not deep frying them? Did you slice them paper-thin? Microwaves vary in power - did you actually cook them until they were done?

Comment: ya.i slice them into paper-thin. fried them 180c

Comment: The recipe you linked to uses a microwave, but you say you "fried them 180C", presumably meaning you fried them at 180C in... a deep-fryer? We really can't help you fix things unless you actually tell us what you did. Failing that, we can't even tell you techniques that make for crispy potato chips if we don't know what equipment you have.

Comment: ya..deep frying

Comment: @Tahmina "moderator attention" under flags means that you have found something wrong with a question or answer, and you ask a mod to look at it and possibly delete it. It doesn't mean that more users who can answer will see the question.

Comment: Hi @Tahmina, we're having difficulty answering your question because it's not clear. You told us in your original post that you microwaved it (you said you "followed this recipe"), then you've told us that you tried to deep fry it at 180C. If you could give a more detailed explanation of exactly what you did we can help. Eg: "I deep fried **** in **** oil in a **** for **** minutes....". Unless you made them in a microwave and are looking for instructions on how to do it in oil? Either way, please clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Speaking as a Brit - we are a nation of chip lovers :)

1. Use an oil which can cope with the high temperature such as groundnut. For that proper chip experience (*** heart attack alert ***) add some beef dripping or lard. I add a small amount to give the chips a nice flavour.
2. Whilst heating the oil regulary dip a chip in the oil. When it starts to bubble then it's time to cook. If the oil is too cold the chips will absorb it and they'll go soggy. (This is easier to achieve with a traditional chip pan or I prefer a deep saucepan).
3. For the perfect chip the potato variety is important but this is personal taste. Last seasons reds will make dark delicious chips but I prefer new potatoes which make a crisper lighter coloured chip. (The potato variety also affects the colour when cooked).
4. Finally, drain on kitchen paper and a sprinkle of salt.

Comment: Mike, the "chip" I believe Tahmina is referring to is the American-style chips--the flat, round variety (I think they go by "crisps" in Britain?).
Does this apply to these as well, or primarily for chips (a.k.a. French Fries for those of us across the pond)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know we were speaking American English and as you correctly state Chips (UK) = Fries (US) and Crisps (UK) = Chips (US). Hence the confusion ("Britain and America are two nations divided by a common language" ;) )

I would imagine you could use the same technique for Crisps (chips) but I would be inclined to leave the dripping or lard out.